# Problem with Arial Font and automatic column breaks

Tags: spacing

I am using 2 columns for a LaTeX article, and I am using `\setmainfont{Arial}`. For some reason, this puts a gigantic amount of whitespace after the beginning of my background section. The problem is that it's not allowing a column break in the paragraph at the beginning of the next section, and this is fixed when I change back to a default font. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: I was a little vague, so here's a minimum working example https://www.overleaf.com/read/kyfrcpbmmpxs . In my case, the white space (after Introduction) is even bigger, but you get the point.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\title{Example}
\author{ericnathanmiller }
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Enim tortor at auctor urna. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit.

Justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Mi eget mauris pharetra et. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet. In arcu cursus euismod quis. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc. Quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim.

Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Fusce id velit ut tortor. Lectus quam id leo in. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare.

\section{Section}
A cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi.

Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Semper eget duis at tellus at. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Et tortor at risus viverra. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi.

Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est.

Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem.

Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean. Proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis. Consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Praesent tristique magna sit amet. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor.

Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus.

Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Non sodales neque sodales ut. Dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. Non arcu risus quis varius. Tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum.
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid that your description ("for some reason" -- really?) is currently rather vague. To give anyone a chance to diagnose the situation and, better still, devise a solution, you need to provide information -- ideally in the form of a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) -- that generates the issue you wish to fix. In particular, do be sure to indicate whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, which document class you employ, which document class options you set, and which packages you load.

Comment: Here is a minimum working example https://www.overleaf.com/read/kyfrcpbmmpxs @Mico

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code here. Your question needs to stay relevant even if the content of the link changes.

Comment: I posted the code @cfr

Comment: I can't test as I don't have the font. Maybe @Mico has it.

Comment: @cfr - Surely you've got Helvetica, though? Arial's nothing but a weak Helvetica clone, its main claim to fame [ouch] having glyph-by-glyph identical metrics...

Comment: @Mico Why would I have Helvetica?

Comment: @cfr - Never mind.

Comment: @Mico Windows users tend to have Arial. Mac users tend to have Helvetica. Linux users ...? I don't know what's metrics equivalent.

Comment: @cfr -- Sorry, for some reason I had you pegged as a Mac user. My apologies.

Comment: @Mico No worries. Was just confused about why everyone would have Helvetica ;). I know more about Macs than Windows, but haven't used one for years. (My last Mac has OS 10.4 and a powerpc chip, which probably makes it antique by now :).)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like less vertical space after a section header, you can change the spacing with a package such as `titlesec`.  One simple way to do this is `\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{Arial}
```

[image: Font sample]

I also removed the `inputenc` package (which is not needed on any TeX engine that supports `fontspec`, and is the default in LaTeX 3 regardless) and added `microtype`, which enables font expansion and protrusion.  This cuts down on greatly on the amount of autohypenation or just plain overflowing the line-breaking algorithm has to do.

If you merely want to inhibit moving the start of Section 2 over to the new column, and increasing the vertical space between the paragraphs of section 1 to fill the height of the page, you could try the `nobottomtitles*` package option.

Another way `titlesec` gives you to solve the problem, at the cost of wasting half a page, is to insert the command `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` into the preamble, or just insert a `\clearpage` before your new `\section`.  This will move the new section to the start of the next page, and the layout of your introduction will not be so distended to match.

(P.S.: if you are writing in a language other than American English, cfr reminds you to load the correct hyphenation patterns through `babel` or `polyglossia`.)

Comment: @cfr I added a postscript.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I can't upvote again. Actually, you should load them even for non-US English because hyphenation patterns differ for e.g. UK English. But for other languages is obviously most important, as you say. (Tidied up a bit.)